# Responsive Design to display List of Data

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I am trying to display a list of data in table on the desktop version of the website using tables. I want to condense the same for the mobile web. Should I use a separate block of html or can I convert the present tables for the mobile view.

http://play.mink7.com/h/startupsradar/pending.html

I like the following list view on mobile

[image]

**Update**
I modified the code according to the answers. Any idea how i can make the whole list as a whole as click-able as one block ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn an HTML `table` to different rendering, e.g. setting

```
table { display: block; }
tr { display: table; }
th, td { display: table-row; }
```

This would cause a completely vertical presentation.

The details of course depend on the markup and on the desired rendering.

Comment: wow. never thought about that. Thank you Sir. any live example where this is used ?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the same block using handheld specific stylesheet attribute `media="screen and (max-device-width: /* whatever */)"` like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="whatever.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: /* whatever */)">
```

Or you can use `@media` inside your stylesheet

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: /* whatever */) {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

[**Media Info**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

> P.S I just saw the source of [nike.com](http://www.nike.com/in/en_gb/), they are using the
>   stylesheet attribute for ipad.css stylesheet, have a look.

Comment: i am already doing that. My question was. should i use Tables for building those list items or should i build them seperately

Comment: `can i convert the present tables for the mobile view.` yes certainly you can, you need to give them separate styles in handheld specific stylesheet, you can read sir Jukka K. Korpela's answer

Comment: cool i did that. Any idea how i can make the whole list as a whole as click-able as one block ?

Comment: You mean your whole layout on the handheld devices should act as link?

Comment: not the whole layout. but the whole row. right now only the image and h2 and p tag act as a link.

Comment: Not sure what you are stating here, you can wrap the area you want to act as a link between anchor tags

Answer (score 1):

If CSS3 is acceptible, you can use [media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to create different styles for different dimensions and devices. You can create incredibly dynamic sites in this way.

Answer (score 1):

In general, table data can stretch tables rows to an undesired length, going out of bounds of the table row. When dealing with mobile devices you will have limited px. You could either create a copy of your existing CSS Stylesheet and edit it slightly setting a min/max width for the table for when your site switched to mobile.

```
max-width: __px;  
min-width: __px; 
etc.
```

Or you could call a JS function on the event of the switch to mobile site appending the CSS

```
$('#tableName').css('max-width', '150px');
$('#tableName').append(div).css('max-width', '150px');
```

The JS version can be a little tricky to get going, I think that you should go with setting limits on the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries i can suggest is the best solution for responsive design.

Let me give you a simple code for responsivenes based on page width.

Here in the code i have using the media queries for changing the para color based on the browser width. You can instead hide using style=display:none or change the size of the contents based on the browser width.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   #p1{
   color:red;
   }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
   #p1{
   color:blue;
   }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p id="p1" media="(max-width: 800px)">Hi , This text colour change according to browser size.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

you can find more tutorial simply [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)